# How to use pocketsphinx in Android Studio

Tags: android, pocketsphinx

I want to use [pocketsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid) but I'm confuse .

1.
I created a model.

2.inside my model I created `main/jniLibs` and copy all belows files and folders :

[image]

now,
- I don't know where can I download `pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-nolib.jar file` .

- Should I use `https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo` as a library ?
- in `MainActivity` I got these errors :

[image]

Comment: Demo's aren't supposed to be used as libraries. They usually compile the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should read over the [Pocketsphinx on Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid#using_pocketsphinx-android) page.

> #### Using pocketsphinx-android
>
> **Referencing the library in Android project**
>
> Library is distributed as architecture-independent
>   pocketsphinx-android-5prealpha-nolib.jar and binary .so files for
>   different hardware architectures.
>
> In Android Studio you need to place jar file in `app/libs` folder and
>   jni .so files into `app/src/main/jniLibs` folder.

In other words, you seem to have missed the JAR file

Otherwise, the other recommendation on that site is to simply clone the demo project, then build your app on top of it rather than copying code around into a new project.